# Mosca Installation failed

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm trying to install Mosca for the first time in my environment. but below are the responds of installation. I got this error. What are the requirement before installing MOSCA after having node.js in our environment?

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:355:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mosca/node_modules/ascoltatori/node_modules/zmq
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing build-essentials.

i.e, on Debian or Ubuntu, type

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials
```

Then above those gyp ERR! messages when you try to npm install again, it should say something like .../lib/X.h fatal error: Y/Y.h: No such file or directory.
Then you just need to Google what libraries use those header files and apt-get install them.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while setting mosca on AWS Ubuntu machine. I had to install the zmq library 
http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software

Note that you will have also install libtool, pkg-config, build-essential, autoconf, and automake.

There is one error in the zmq installation doc. I needed to run 'sudo make install', instead of just 'make install' as suggested in the doc.